# Attempted Import error: 'SomeModule' is not exported from './some/path';

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

Suddenly, I am getting this error while running my app.

I have imported FloatingLabel from react-bootstrap only which is correct as far as I know.

[image]

My code is

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Row, Col, Container, FloatingLabel} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './login.css';

class LoginForm extends React.Component
{
   FormExample() 
    {
        return (
            <Container fluid="sm">
                <Row lg={12}>
                    <Col lg={6} className="m-auto border border-2 border-dark box-shadow">
                        <Container className="text-center mt-2">
                            <h2 className="text-center">Login</h2>
                            <p>Sign into your account here</p>
                        </Container>
                        <Form noValidate aria-label="Login">
                            <Row md={12} className="mb-3">
                                <Form.Group as={Col} md={10} className="m-auto" controlId="formGroupPassword">
                                    <FloatingLabel label="Password" controlId="password">
                                        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
                                    </FloatingLabel>
                                   </Form.Group>
                            </Row>                   
                            <Row md={12} className="mb-3" >
                                <Form.Group as={Col} md={10} className="m-auto">
                                    <Form.Check required name="terms" label="Agree to terms and conditions" id="terms"/>
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Row>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
    render()
    {
        return(this.FormExample());
    } 
}  

export default LoginForm;
```

Can somebody help me understand why I am getting this error even if I have imported the proper module?

Comment: Which version of react-bootstrap are you running? Try to install it again.

Comment: I think I am using latest version, which is `react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1"`

Answer (score 1):

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/forms/#floating-label-props

Try this^.

`import FloatingLabel from 'react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel'`

Comment: It's still not working for me, already have gone through with that link